# Notepad ++ advanced replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm having some trouble about replacing option string. I need to replace:

tag1 any word or numbers tag1

to

tag2 any word or numbers tag2

However, the text between tags can not be changed and it is variable.

Example:

From:
tag1 America tag1
tag1 Africa tag1
tag1 South America tag1
tag1 Asia tag1
tag1 Oceania tag1

To:

tag2 America tag2
tag2 Africa tag2
tag2 South America tag2
tag2 Asia tag2
tag2 Oceania tag2

There is about 50.000 lines with diferent texts between tag1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) using the <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**H**</kbd> option and then by replacing **`tag1`** with **`tag2`** and the other options set as listed below in the screen shot and pointed out specifically. This will work with the **Search Mode** set to **Regular Expression** or as **Normal Search**.

[image]
[image]

### Before

> ```
> tag1 America tag1
> tag1 Africa tag1
> tag1 South America tag1
> tag1 Asia tag1
> tag1 Oceania tag1
> ```

### After

> ```
> tag2 America tag2
> tag2 Africa tag2
> tag2 South America tag2
> tag2 Asia tag2
> tag2 Oceania tag2
> ```

Comment: This approach probably fails if the file contains an odd number of occurrences of tag1.

Comment: even normal notepad which comes with windows could do this :o

Answer (score 1):

Find what:

```
tag1(.*)tag1
```

Replace with:

```
replacement1$1replacement2
```

[x] Regular expression

Hereby `replacement1` or `replacement2` may be equal to `tag1`.